# How to convert dom nodes to array?

Tags: php, dom

I have this function that takes dom nodes and create an array from them.
But it gives only a part of the page I think it's about siblings but don't find how to modify it:

```
function nodeToArray( $dom, $node)
{
    if(!is_a( $dom, 'DOMDocument' ) || !is_a( $node, 'DOMNode' )) {
        return false;
    }
    $array = false; 
    if( empty( trim( $node->localName ))) {// Discard empty nodes
        return false;
    }
    if( XML_TEXT_NODE == $node->nodeType ) {
        return $node->nodeValue;
    }
    foreach ($node->attributes as $attr) { 
        $array['@'.$attr->localName] = $attr->nodeValue; 
    } 
    foreach ($node->childNodes as $childNode) { 
        if ( 1 == $childNode->childNodes->length && XML_TEXT_NODE == $childNode->firstChild->nodeType ) { 
            $array[$childNode->localName] = $childNode->nodeValue; 
        }  else {
            if( false !== ($a = nodeToArray( $dom, $childNode))) {
                $array[$childNode->localName] =     $a;
            }
        }
    }
    return $array; 
}

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($response);
$a=nodeToArray($dom,$dom->getElementsByTagName("body")->item(0));
print "<pre>";
print_r($a);
print "</pre>";
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you isolate the problem and show us what is not working with the sample input rather than dropping random snippet of code?

Comment: the childnodes loop is going to save only the **LAST** of any particular node encountered. if you have (say) 6 `<p>` tags in there, you'll overwrite the stuff you've saved from nodes 1->5, and leave only 6 in there.